# Implementing the Legendre Function in R

Tags: r, function, math

I'd like to write a function in R that is defined in terms of the Legendre function of degree $\nu$ and order $m$, where these could be fractional. The function I'd like to implement is featured on the right-hand side of Result 3.664.4 in [this table of integrals.](http://fisica.ciens.ucv.ve/%7Esvincenz/TISPISGIMR.pdf)

[image]

Could someone please help me to reproduce this Legendre function, which is more general than the one provided in [the Pracma package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pracma/versions/1.9.9/topics/legendre#), in R? To double check that it works, perhaps it'd be useful to reproduce the probability density [given here](https://rdrr.io/cran/circular/man/jonespewsey.html) for the parameters $1/\psi$ and $0$. This is one of the few examples of an R function that uses this more general form of the Legendre function.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck? Is your second parameter supposed to be $\mu$ rather than $\nu$?

Comment: The [cooltools package](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/cooltools/html/alp.html) claims to have the associated Legendre polynomials P, although I don't know if fractional indices are allowed.  This problem seems like it could be difficult ...

Comment: `?gsl::Legendre` might also be helpful, you'd have to look [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/specfunc.html#legendre-functions-and-spherical-harmonics) and cross-reference with Abramowitz and Stegun ...

Comment: @BenBolker Yeah, it doesn't seem to be ideal

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but I think this question is asking for a lot. Unless someone happens to have a solution up their sleeve or have done something very similarl, to answer it we have to dig down into the reference material, figure out what all the notation refers to, see if those special functions are implemented somewhere or if they can be implemented reasonably easily/stably, .... again, **what have  you tried**?

Comment: Also remember that this is not the [math.se] site: as per the [markdown](/markdown) explainer, there is no LaTeX support here. So, [edit] your post to turn those LaTeX variables into code markup instead.

Comment: Will, looks like you might get some ideas about identities that are applicable here from math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the numeric computation perspective, probably you can define the function based on the integral expression, e.g.,

```
f <- function(z, mu, nu) {
    integrand <- function(x) {
        (z + sqrt(z^2 - 1) * cos(x))^mu * sin(x)^(2 * nu - 1)
    }
    if (!is.complex(z) && abs(z) < 1) {
        z <- as.complex(z)
    }
    re <- integrate(\(x) Re(integrand(x)), 0, pi)$value
    im <- integrate(\(x) Im(integrand(x)), 0, pi)$value
    ifelse(im == 0, re, re + 1i * im)
}
```

I don't have much experience on Legendre function or polynomials, but you can try and verify if it works properly.

Comment: This is a good solution, although I tried to test it when applied to the density with suitable values for x,k,p and m [ jpd <-function(x,k,p,m) {(cosh(k*p)+sinh(k*p)*cos(x-m))^(1/p)/(2*pi*f(cosh(k*p),1/p,0))} ] and it seems to raise the error "Error in integrate(function(x) Re(integrand(x)), 0, pi) : 
  roundoff error is detected in the extrapolation table". I'm not too familiar with R and I'm still on a learning curve, so any help in identifying and resolving these issues would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your contribution to this question so far. You've been very helpful.

Comment: Update: fixed the problem